# Turning off the ability to suspend on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: suspend

When I suspend Ubuntu I can't get out of the suspend screen. Yes, I know there are ways to fix this but that would take forever to fix. Is there a way to disable the ability to suspend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To a point you could control this in policykit, in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy` and or `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy`

The relevant entries would be `org.freedesktop.upower.suspend` & `org.freedesktop.login1.suspend` respectively

In that case editing the line `<allow_active>yes</allow_active>` to `<allow_active>no</allow_active>` would work.

It's probable that in 13.10 policykit is no longer used for this so those edits would have no effect. In that case you could figure out how hibernate has been disabled & do the same for suspend or cause power management to inhibit suspend altogether.

The latter could be done as such -

`sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/00_cancel-suspend`

copy & paste this in -

```
#!/bin/sh
# prevents suspend
. "$PM_FUNCTIONS"
case "${1}" in
  suspend)
    inhibit
    ;;
  resume)
    exit 0
    ;;
esac
```

Then on keyboard go

ctrl+o

enter

ctrl+x

to save & exit nano

Finish with -

```
sudo chmod 0755  /etc/pm/sleep.d/00_cancel-suspend
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it actually worked but weirdly enough when I tried suspend it worked. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1):

That should be easy!

Open System Settings (Top right button) --> Power options --> Set lid options to Nothing.

Comment: I've already domes that, but under the available options when I press the power button on my MBP it shows lock suspend restart and shut down. I want it to be physically impossible to make it go into suspend mode